# JAVA - Speed up the code

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I want to speed up the my code. Quick status information:

- There is more than one list (`String`) like `_list1`, `_list2`, `_list3`.
- I try to find a word (`String`) in these lists.
- If I find a word, I will use index of the word on the list.

Here is my code:

```
private static int foundIndex (String s) 
{
    if (_list1.contains(s)) {
        return _list1.indexOf(s);
    } else if (_list2.contains(s)) {
        return _list2.indexOf(s);
    } else if (_list3.contains(s)) {
        return _list3.indexOf(s);
    } else if (_list4.contains(s)) {
        return _list4.indexOf(s);
    }
...
...
...
...
    } else if (_list100.contains(s)) {
        return _list100.indexOf(s);
    }
    return -1;
}
```

How can I speed up the my code?

Comment: You can map `s` to an index in a `Map<String, Integer>`.

Comment: What Java version?

Comment: return index when list is not known ... isn't too much useable

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I think it belongs to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Have you heard of **arrays**? Having 100 fields named `_list1`, `_list2`, ..., `_list99`, and `_list100` is really bad code.

Answer (score 2):

A couple simple optimizations comes to mind:

1.replace the `if (contains) then indexOf` pattern with `if (i = indexOf(s) >= 0) return i`

2.add lookup data structure like a `Map<String,Integer>` and either use it instead of the lists or in addition to them by updating it whenever you add or change a list

Answer (score 1):

Add all your lists (`String`) in a `List<String>` and iterate on it :

```
private static int foundIndex (String s) {
   for (String currentList : lists){
       int indexOf = currentList.indexOf(s);
       if (indexOf != -1) {
          return indexOf;
       }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: return index when list is not known ... isn't too much useable (like in primary solution)

Comment: @Jacek Cz  Possible. I don't know the need. With a few modification, it may return a custom class `ListAndIndex` that contains both the index and the List.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the algorithm of my code to your suggestions.
I was use list to much before, now I changed it. I use 2D String array.
But code performance was 157% decrease.

New Code :

```
private static String[][] _lists = new String[200][100];

private static int foundIndex (String s) {
for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
            if (_lists[i][j].equals(s) == true) {
                return j;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

That's where the problem starts.

If the code I'm looking for is "_list[180][?]", it's hard to find it.

How can I speed up the my code?

Thank you.